# Ubuntu 18.04 with Apogee ONE audio interface, Sound and PulseAudio show the ONEv2 Analog Stereo flashing each second but cannot select it

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, interface

How to select the Apogee ONEv2 device for mic input? It's flashing but unable to select it. It was selectable back in 2009 according to this post: [Apogee ONE works with Linux!! (partially)](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/low-end-theory/456989-apogee-one-works-linux-partially.html). It is flashing both as an output device and as an input device. GNOME ALSA Mixer settings don't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The ApogeeONE driver is included in the company's softwre which is only written for W10 and Mac. It is NOT USB 2.0 compliant, so it does not work with Linux (unless someone writes a driver). So the post by someone in 2009 saying that it worked does not apply at this time.
Audio interfaces that are USB 2.0 compliant, such as Scarlett, Komplete6 and others, are USB 2.0 compliant and work when plugged in since the drivers are included in the Linux kernels. This site lists some audio devices that definitely work with Linux. (It could use updating.) https://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/hardware_support